# Что за CMS такая?

Tags: php, html, css, cms

Можете подсказать название CMS
на котором создаются блоги.

https://www.blogger.com/

Comment: Дак `blogger` и создан для создания блогов, если вы не заметили. И у них своя `CMS`, а точнее свой `движек`.

Comment: @And, как его скачать в виде архива например... у них есть CMS эта чтобы на хостинг залить...

Comment: Ага, еще скажите как гугл поисковик скачать архивом. В прямом доступе не найдете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и называется "Blogger"
ссылка:
https://whatcms.org/c/Blogger

Comment: а как скачать эту cms ? архивом...

Comment: Я не искал инфу но судя по всему никак, это cms гугла.